# Magento error in sales_order when active one of standard filter

Tags: upgrade, admin-panel, fatal-error

After upgrade my magento to 1.9 in sales order if I active an filter as particular name od order_id I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /.../public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Editroles.php on line 44

have you any information or suggest for this error?

---UPDATE ---

If I replace Editroles.php with original code

```
$this->_title($this->__('System'))
             ->_title($this->__('Permissions'))
             ->_title($this->__('Roles'));

        $role = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam($requestVariable));
        // preventing edit of relation role
        if ($role->getId() && $role->getRoleType() != 'G') {
            $role->unsetData($role->getIdFieldName());
        }

        $role = Mage::register('current_role', $role);
```

The fatal error disappear but I have an error js on prototype.js that redirect me on dashboard of admin

Comment: Can you post the javascript error? If you have edited core code it's gonna be hard to help you since we can't reproduce the issue